# Not able to connect socket.io in nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Hi I am trying to setup a connection with socket.IO but not able to do so. At present I am not getting any error but the connection is not taking place.Please find below the relevant details :

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
require('./db/mongoose');
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io');
socket = io(http, {cors: {
  origin: "http://localhost",
  methods: ["GET", "POST"]
}
});
var cors = require("cors");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');

app.use(cors()); 

const portCheck = process.env.PORT || 3001

socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected to socket');
  socket.emit('greeting-from-server', {
      greeting: 'Hello Client'
  });
});


 app.listen(portCheck, ()=> {
            console.log('Server Listening to port:' + portCheck);
 })
```

Comment: You are mixing both socket.io client and server code here.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Are you trying to set up a socket.io  server that others can connect to?  Or trying to make a socket.io connection to some other socket.io server?

Comment: Also, you will only see errors if you listen for the `error` event or turn on socket.io debugging.  That would probably help you see what's happening.  Pretty much every event-driven object (like a socket.io client or server) has an `error` event that gets triggered when errors occur.  You should always be listening to these so you can log errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes should done for your code as follows:**

1. Change app listen with server listen
2. wrap `socket.on(//...)` with `io.on(//...)`
3. replace this lines

```
const app = express();const http = 
require('http').createServer(app);
```

with

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

After the changes code is like follows.

```
const express = require('express');
require('./db/mongoose');
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
socket = io(http, {cors: {
  origin: "http://localhost",
  methods: ["GET", "POST"]
}
});
var cors = require("cors");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');

app.use(cors()); 

const portCheck = process.env.PORT || 3001
server.listen(portCheck, ()=> {
            console.log('Server Listening to port:' + portCheck);
 })

io.on('connection', (socket)=> {

  socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connected to socket');
  socket.emit('greeting-from-server', {
      greeting: 'Hello Client'
       });
    });
});
```

follow more information through this link. https://socket.io/get-started/chat.

Comment: Answers with no explanation at all for what you thought the problem was and what you changed and why are just not as useful as pure code answers.  You are requiring other viewers to manually do a visual diff to try to figure out what changed and why.  Please explain what the problem was and what you changed and why.

Comment: I will add them. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated and added reference and this way it worked for me. My repo link where I used same thing  for create socket connection. https://github.com/yasiruRathnayaka97/pdfLibrest/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I would  argue that the OP's question is not clear.  They show code for both a socket.io server AND a socket.io client.  The question does not explain exactly what doesn't work.  Maybe this guess solves their issue, maybe not because the precise issue is not clear - thus why my comment to the OP to clarify  their question.  They also have no error reporting so we don't even know what error they might be getting (if any).

Comment: You are right. I agree with you. I posted this answer because When I implement sockets I faced similar issue like this.  I could not observe any error similar as this case. Therefore I assumed that this is the same issue I faced. Thanks for your guide.